# Web service development on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, netbeans

We used to develop web services in netbeans and deploy them to tomcat. It was pretty seamless and almost everything worked out of the box. Now we have to shift to eclipse. I am trying to create a soap based web service using metro web services runtime. As some benchmarks on internet suggest that axis is slow as compared to metro ( I found it a little difficult too).

I guess i'll have to stick with metro But where is the option for selecting metro as the web services runtime in eclipse java ee IDE?

Is there any tutorial for netbeans users to create service on eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

I used cxf and i liked it.Well for metro integration refer [this](http://blog.arungupta.me/2009/08/totd-98-create-a-metro-jax-ws-web-service-using-glassfish-tools-bundle-for-eclipse/) link